# Python ttk.OptionMenu Option Font Style

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

Before you call this a duplicate of any existing post on StackOverflow, please read:

I have a `ttk.OptionMenu` widget and I cannot seem to shift the style of the options in the widget. The style that I have applied has only modified the display box for the selected entry, but I am interested in changing the font style of the drop-down so that it matches the selected option as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

optList1 = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
    ]

var1 = tk.StringVar(root)
var1.set(optList1[0]) #first value default

someStyle=ttk.Style()
someStyle.configure('my.TMenubutton',font=('Futura',20))

optMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var1, optList1[0], *optList1, style='my.TMenubutton')
optMenu1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I am unsure why the defined style does not apply to the options that display and I would appreciate any help on this. My suspicion is that the drop-down selections are using some separately defined font style that could potentially be a system font setting.

Comment: Try `optMenu1['menu'].configure(font=('Futura',20))`

Comment: @stovfl thank you very much! I had seen many answers in the past with the `menuname` portion of the configure statement, but that must not exist in the `ttk.Optionmenu` variant because it says that the attribute does not exist. This solved my problem! 

Please copy this to an answer so I can choose this as an answer for future people to benefit from!

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure dropdown selections separately by using:

```py
optMenu1['menu'].configure(font=('Futura',20))
```

Here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()

optList1 = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
    ]

var1 = tk.StringVar(root)
var1.set(optList1[0]) #first value default

someStyle=ttk.Style()
someStyle.configure('my.TMenubutton',font=('Futura',20))

optMenu1 = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var1, optList1[0], *optList1, style='my.TMenubutton')
optMenu1['menu'].configure(font=('Futura',20))#add this to your code it will change style for dropdownlist
optMenu1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try:
>
> ```
> optMenu1['menu'].configure(font=('Futura',20))
> ```

stovfl, Feb 11 (2019) at 22:15

Comment: Add more details to your answer will help users.

Comment: This is literally a copy-paste of a comment to the question...